# (PIL) Image.paste not functioning as intended

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've been trying to overlay 2 images of different sizes together. 3 smaller images on top of 1 big image. However, once I use paste, it distorts the image and doesn't help in my scenario..

Edited simple example:

```
    new_im = Image.open(f"./emotes/blue.jpg")
    new_im2 = Image.open(f"./emotes/black.jpg")
    new_im.paste(new_im2)
```

Using blue and black gives me the result I want; an Image with 100% opaque overlayed on top of another.

However, if I use 2 different set of images, using the same code, I get a distorted image.

Examples are fully shown in https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrQ51.jpg.

EDIT: JPG as the background image makes the paste work as intended. Not sure why PNG doesn't work; probably an issue with transparency?

Comment: I've looked at example image and find it difficult to see the distortion you talk about. Please provide a [mre] that only pastes one image — and one in whitch the problem is obvious.

Comment: @martineau Hey, I edited the post with the images used and the full examples. Let me know if this helps or if I need to clarify anything, thank you

Comment: It is still hard to see what you are trying to do and what the problem is.

Comment: Your new image is blank.

Comment: The non-working background image is probably a palette-based image - the pasted images have no colors available to them other than those already in that palette.  Convert it to RGB first, so the image can hold all colors.